# Is function passed to std::for_each allowed to make copies of sequence elements?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I've recently stumbled upon this wording from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

> Unlike the rest of the algorithms, for_each is not allowed to make copies of the elements in the sequence even if they are trivially copyable.

Is the statement correct? I haven't found any grounds in the standard. Do I understand well, that it would btw. imply the following example from the same page invalid?

```
struct Sum
{
    Sum(): sum{0} { }
    void operator()(int n) { sum += n; }
    int sum;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 8, 15, 267};
 
    // ...
 
    // calls Sum::operator() for each number
    Sum s = std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), Sum());
 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `std::for_each` returns void, so this won't compile. You're looking for `std::accumulate`

Comment: I'm afraid You are wrong on this one. Anyway, this is not the point of the question and I am not looking for any particular solution.

Comment: It might be because the implementation of for_each can be written without requiring that the value type of the dereferenced iterators meets the requirement of CopyConstructible. If that is the case then you have no guarrantee that code that assumes the type is CopyConstructable will work.

Comment: You're reading it backwards. You are interpreting it as "The UnaryFunction is not allowed to make copies of elements", but the statement is saying that **`for_each` itself** is not allowed to make copies. This is a restriction on the library author, not on you the library user. This restriction is important so that you can `for_each` over a collection of non-copyable objects (such as `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: You've certainly hit the nail here. Thank you!

Comment: @neonxc Just checked again - you're right. I wonder why I thought that.

Comment: @RaymondChen Right answers in comment are problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording is indeed confusing, as it is also mentionned that

> The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>   void fun(const Type &a); 
>   The signature does not need to have const &.

I think you need to see the fact that `for_each` is not allowed to make copies of the elements as a guarantee given by the standard to the user rather than a limitation on the user predicate function applied to each element..

Comment: The signature does not need to have `const &`, because you could ommit the `const` for instance. In my opinion, this is a rather generic paragraph used across many pages.

Comment: you can omit either or both. I think you misunderstood what I meant by *it*

Answer (score 4):

That sentence on cppreference.com comes from the wording added to C++17 about the new support for parallel algorithms.

[[algorithms.parallel.exec]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/algorithms.parallel.exec#3) says:

> Unless otherwise stated, implementations may make arbitrary copies of elements (with type `T`) from sequences where `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>` and `is_­trivially_­destructible_­v<T>` are true.

Note this is in a context discussing parallel algorithms, defined as standard library function templates which have a template parameter named `ExecutionPolicy`.

But then [[alg.foreach]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/algorithms#alg.foreach-9) says of `for_each(ExecutionPolicy&&, ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, Function)`:

> Implementations do not have the freedom granted under [algorithms.parallel.exec] to make arbitrary copies of elements from the input sequence.

Presumably some parallelization techniques can be more efficient for trivial types by making copies of the elements.  (Maybe to make them contiguous in memory? I'm just guessing.)

So none of this applies to the older non-parallel `for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f)`.  For that algorithm, it's simply the case that since the [effects](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/algorithms#alg.foreach-2) are specified as "Applies `f` to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range `[first, last)`...", the functor argument must be e.g. `*first` and not a copy of `*first`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find it very informative. On the other hand, @UmNyobe's answer is probably more relevant to the topic of my question. Please don't take this badly. I do value your effort.